# UIGestureRecognizer oneFingerForcePress: crash on iOS 11

Tags: ios11

We just got some weird crashes feedback on iPhone device iOS 11.
Here is a information:

`UIKit: -[_UIKeyBoardBasedNonEditableTextSelectionGestureCluster oneFingerForcePress:]`

I just can't figure it out what `UIKeyBoardBasedNonEditableTextSelectionGestureCluster` is. Have any idea?

[image]

Comment: Is UIWebView used in your application?

Comment: Oh yes, we have. Why is UIWebView?

Comment: I saw similar crashes in our app (also on iOS 10 btw). According to reports from our users, the crash can happen when a text entry in the UIWebView receives focus (e.g. by tap). I believe it's because of some internal UIWebView bugs (like [this one](https://github.com/guarani/WebViewDoubleTapTestTests))