# _UIKeyboardBasedNonEditableTextSelectionGestureCluster oneFingerForcePress: Crash in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, crash, crash-reports

I have a crash log like the below could not able to find the reason for the crash. It's the crash log from the customer. No proper steps to reproduce it. What might be the reason for the crash?

```
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001807f4430 objc_msgSend + 16
1   UIKit                           0x000000018afad990 -[_UIKeyboardBasedNonEditableTextSelectionGestureCluster oneFingerForcePress:] + 76 (_UIKeyboardTextSelectionGestureController.m:2076)
2   UIKit                           0x000000018b060134 -[UIGestureRecognizerTarget _sendActionWithGestureRecognizer:] + 64 (UIGestureRecognizer.m:105)
3   UIKit                           0x000000018b064698 _UIGestureRecognizerSendTargetActions + 124 (UIGestureRecognizer.m:1128)
4   UIKit                           0x000000018b064514 -[UIGestureRecognizer _forceLevelClassifier:currentForceLevelDidChange:] + 360 (UIGestureRecognizer.m:1736)
5   UIKit                           0x000000018aedb538 -[_UIForceLevelClassifier setCurrentForceLevel:] + 108 (_UIForceLevelClassifier.m:69)
6   UIKit                           0x000000018b5911a8 -[_UILinearForceLevelClassifier observeTouchWithForceValue:atTimestamp:withCentroidAtLocation:] + 160 (_UILinearForceLevelClassifier.m:162)
7   UIKit                           0x000000018aedb7a4 __48-[_UIForceLevelClassifier receiveObservedValue:]_block_invoke + 160 (_UIForceLevelClassifier.m:87)
8   UIKit                           0x000000018b06e9d0 -[_UITouchForceMessage ifObservation:ifReset:] + 304 (_UITouchForceMessage.m:60)
9   UIKit                           0x000000018aedb6ac -[_UIForceLevelClassifier receiveObservedValue:] + 288 (_UIForceLevelClassifier.m:93)
10  Foundation                      0x00000001820c50a4 -[_NSObserverList _receiveBox:] + 572 (NSObservedValue.h:53)
```

Comment: Is your app using UIWebview?

Comment: Yes it is using UIWebview.

Comment: seem like it's a bug of UIWebView. Reference here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46443341/uigesturerecognizer-onefingerforcepress-crash-on-ios-11. You can try to using WKWebView for fix it or ignore it

Comment: Quoc Nguyen code is written like this. If above ios 11.0 its using WKWebview or else it's using UIWebview

Comment: from iOS 8, you can use WKWebView. In the Apple's doc (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview), they said `
Starting in iOS 8.0 and OS X 10.10, use WKWebView to add web content to your app. Do not use UIWebView or WebView.` too